# My reference to NSFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects changes as the NSManagedObject changes

Tags: swift, core-data, combine

I'm new to CoreData and I believe that what I'm looking at here is expected behavior, but it is confusing me nonetheless and could use some clarity from someone more experienced.

I have the following custom Combine publisher that wraps `NSFetchedResultsController`, and emits a `CollectionDifference` that describes how the results from the NSFetchRequest change over time - I want to use this to bind Core Data to my UI. For now, I'm using a single NSManagedObjectContext on the main queue, but I hope to eventually support a background queue context so that my Publisher can emit changes no matter what context the changes occurred on.

When I insert and delete, the collection difference emitted is what I expect.

However, if I update an NSManagedObject and save, the `lastSentState` in my Publisher implementation is updated from underneath me, and when I go to compute differences between `lastSentState` and `fetchedObjects` - I always get that there are no differences.

I am assuming this is because I'm dealing with a reference type. What confuses me a bit is that the documentation for `fetchedObjects` says:

> The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store. The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.

I expected based on this that my reference to `fetchedObjects` in `lastSentState` would not be updated, but I suppose what I'm seeing is that `lastSentState` is updated because their references (even though they were fetched from a separate fetch request) were updated in memory.

Here is how I'm updating my item in CoreData:

```swift
    func update(_ task: Task) async throws {
        try await coreDataStack.container.viewContext.performChanges {
            let fetch = TaskEntity.fetchRequest()
            fetch.predicate = .init(format: "%K == %@", "id", task.id as CVarArg)
            fetch.sortDescriptors = []
            let results = try coreDataStack.container.viewContext.fetch(fetch)
            for result in results where result.id == task.id {
                result.id = task.id
                result.creationDate = task.creationDate
                result.title = task.title
                try coreDataStack.container.viewContext.save()
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my Publisher. The pertinent part in code for this question is `lastSentState`

```swift
import Combine
import CoreData

extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func changesPublisher<Object: NSManagedObject>(for fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object>)
        -> ManagedObjectChangesPublisher<Object>
    {
        ManagedObjectChangesPublisher(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, context: self)
    }
}

struct ManagedObjectChangesPublisher<Object: NSManagedObject>: Publisher {
    typealias Output = CollectionDifference<Object>
    typealias Failure = Error

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object>
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object>, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.fetchRequest = fetchRequest
        self.context = context
    }

    func receive<S: Subscriber>(subscriber: S) where Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        let inner = Inner(downstream: subscriber, fetchRequest: fetchRequest, context: context)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: inner)
    }

    private final class Inner<Downstream: Subscriber>: NSObject, Subscription,
        NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    where Downstream.Input == CollectionDifference<Object>, Downstream.Failure == Error {
        private let downstream: Downstream
        private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Object>?

        init(
            downstream: Downstream,
            fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object>,
            context: NSManagedObjectContext
        ) {
            self.downstream = downstream
            fetchedResultsController
                = NSFetchedResultsController(
                    fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                    managedObjectContext: context,
                    sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                    cacheName: nil)

            super.init()

            fetchedResultsController!.delegate = self

            do {
                try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
                updateDiff()
            } catch {
                downstream.receive(completion: .failure(error))
            }
        }

        private var demand: Subscribers.Demand = .none

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            self.demand += demand
            fulfillDemand()
        }

        private var lastSentState: [Object] = []
        private var currentDifferences = CollectionDifference<Object>([])!

        private func updateDiff() {
            currentDifferences
                = Array(fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects ?? []).difference(
                    from: lastSentState)
            fulfillDemand()
        }

        private func fulfillDemand() {
            if demand > 0 && !currentDifferences.isEmpty {
                let newDemand = downstream.receive(currentDifferences)
                lastSentState = Array(fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects ?? [])
                currentDifferences = lastSentState.difference(from: lastSentState)

                demand += newDemand
                demand -= 1
            }
        }

        func cancel() {
            fetchedResultsController?.delegate = nil
            fetchedResultsController = nil
        }

        func controllerDidChangeContent(
            _ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
        ) {
            updateDiff()
        }

        override var description: String {
            "ManagedObjectChanges(\(Object.self))"
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get things working as I expect if I map the NSManagedObjects in my Publisher to a value type - so I made the Publisher generic over a type that knows how to convert from a "managed object" to a "non managed object"

But I'm unsure if this is a good strategy.

I'd appreciate insight on what I'm observing here and on whether mapping to a value type makes sense/won't cause problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've got something nearly identical and keep running into data races when the delegate method is called under some specific situations. 

This became more clear after turning on Thread Sanitizer diagnostic for the scheme. Trying to debug this now, but it seems there are multiple Inners and they get called on different threads.

I really which there was some way to get the results as an AsyncThrowingStream. You can always call .values on the publisher, but a first party solution would be much preferred. 

With SwiftData, this seems unlikely.